# Ubuntu server installation on headless server: stuck

Tags: ubuntu, installation, headless

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22 - server on a headless server. It doesn't even have VGA/HDMI output. So I have prepared a usb stick with ubuntu installer. I am connecting via RS232. Once I get to grub, and choose Install Ubuntu option, the machine freezes. I tried adding *nomodeset* and *gfxpayload=text* but it just doesn't work. I've been running ubuntu on that machine before, so it's not a matter of hardware. I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.